# Prediction values using svm

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I have the following dataset (df):

```
 won  EXPG1   EXPG2
41   1 1.4200 0.93285
42   0 1.3105 1.11580
43   2 1.3678 0.90433
44   2 1.1773 0.96671
45   2 1.3541 0.89154
46   2 1.1768 0.99026
```

I would like to prodict the value won based on a svm model. So therefore I do:

```
#create traing/test set
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=df$won, p=0.7, list=FALSE)
training <- df[inTrain, ]
testing <- df[-inTrain, ]


#create model
model <- svm(won ~ EXPG1 + EXPG2 , training)
Prediction <- predict(model, testing)
conf <- confusionMatrix(Prediction, testing$won)
```

When I hit conf this however gives me the following values:

```
Pos Pred Value         0.5150      NaN   0.4817
```

I dont understand why I do not get a positive predictive value for 1. Could anybody explain to me what goes wrong?

This is my complete confusionmatrix:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

      Reference
Prediction   0   1   2
     0 130  55  51
     1   0   0   0
     2 281 350 603

Overall Statistics

           Accuracy : 0.4986          
             95% CI : (0.4728, 0.5245)
No Information Rate : 0.4449          
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1.992e-05       

              Kappa : 0.138           
Mcnemar's Test P-Value : < 2.2e-16       

Statistics by Class:

                 Class: 0 Class: 1 Class: 2
Sensitivity           0.31630   0.0000   0.9220
Specificity           0.89991   1.0000   0.2267
Pos Pred Value        0.55085      NaN   0.4887
Neg Pred Value        0.77229   0.7245   0.7839
Prevalence            0.27959   0.2755   0.4449
Detection Rate        0.08844   0.0000   0.4102
Detection Prevalence  0.16054   0.0000   0.8395
Balanced Accuracy     0.60810   0.5000   0.5744
```

Comment: Can you provide the full output from `confusionMatrix`?

Comment: @cdeterman of course. I edited my question...

Comment: Your SVM model didn't classify any in your testing dataset as `1` so there is no PPV to be calculated.  You model needs to be tuned further.  Also, it may be a good idea to check that there were any `1`'s in your test dataset just to be sure.

Comment: Hm ok, gonna look into it. If i check my testing set I see that I have >400 1 values... Kind of strange that the miodel doesn't pick them up right?